# Jekyll Paginator Rendering Pages But No Output

Tags: pagination, jekyll, jekyll-paginator

I'm using jekyll 3.1.2 with the jekyll-paginator to try and create a website that has a homepage at index.html and a blog at /blog/index.html. The website is generated correctly (including each post in the output directory), but the blog directory is not generating the pagination directories. Here is my config:

```
gems: [jekyll-paginate]

# Site settings
title: Site Title
description: >
  Description here
baseurl: "/" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "http://<my url here>com" # the base hostname & protocol for your site

# Build settings
markdown: kramdown
paginate: 3
paginate_path: "/blog/page:num/"
```

I have a bunch of posts that generate HTML properly in the output folder but the /blog subdirectory only has the index.html file, no subdirectories...however, using the verbose output I see the following during generation:

```
       Rendering: /blog/page2/index.html
  Pre-Render Hooks: /blog/page2/index.html
  Rendering Liquid: /blog/page2/index.html
  Rendering Markup: /blog/page2/index.html
  Rendering Layout: /blog/page2/index.html
         Rendering: /blog/page3/index.html
  Pre-Render Hooks: /blog/page3/index.html
  Rendering Liquid: /blog/page3/index.html
  Rendering Markup: /blog/page3/index.html
  Rendering Layout: /blog/page3/index.html
         Rendering: /blog/page4/index.html
  Pre-Render Hooks: /blog/page4/index.html
  Rendering Liquid: /blog/page4/index.html
  Rendering Markup: /blog/page4/index.html
  Rendering Layout: /blog/page4/index.html
         Rendering: /blog/page5/index.html
  Pre-Render Hooks: /blog/page5/index.html
  Rendering Liquid: /blog/page5/index.html
  Rendering Markup: /blog/page5/index.html
  Rendering Layout: /blog/page5/index.html
         Rendering: /blog/page6/index.html
  Pre-Render Hooks: /blog/page6/index.html
  Rendering Liquid: /blog/page6/index.html
  Rendering Markup: /blog/page6/index.html
  Rendering Layout: /blog/page6/index.html
         Rendering: /blog/page7/index.html
  Pre-Render Hooks: /blog/page7/index.html
  Rendering Liquid: /blog/page7/index.html
  Rendering Markup: /blog/page7/index.html
  Rendering Layout: /blog/page7/index.html
```

Any ideas why the subdirectories will not show up in the output folder?

Comment: Perhaps something wrong with the layouts or includes. Can you post your repository url?

Comment: I am also getting this problem. I have a custom setup though so I am not sure if I did something wrong. I did find this issue with Jekyll though: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4568. The pagination works fine on a fresh project though. :(